# JToken and Dictionary recursion to infer JSON from XML

Tags: c#

I need to turn an XML file into JSON in WPF C#. The problem is that inside there is not a single unique ID and there are several recursions.
The XML I have is this:

```
<FIRSTLEVEL>
        <SECONDLEVEL>
          <FIRSTLOOP ID="0">
            <SUBLOOP>
              <FIRST ID="-1" DESC="TEXT2">
                <END/>
              </FIRST>
              <FIRST ID="1" DESC="TEXT3">
                <END/>
              </FIRST>
              <FIRST ID="2" DESC="TEXT4">
                <END/>
              </FIRST>
              <FIRST ID="3" DESC="TEXT5">
                <END/>
              </FIRST>
            </SUBLOOP>
          </FIRSTLOOP>
          <FIRSTLOOP ID="1" DESC="TEXT6">
            <SUBLOOP>
              <FIRST ID="-1" DESC="TEXT7">
                <END>
                  <FULL IDFIRSTLOOP="0" IDFIRST="-1" />
                </END>
              </FIRST>
              <FIRST ID="0" DESC="TEXT8">
                <END>
                  <FULL IDFIRSTLOOP="0" IDFIRST="-1" />
                </END>
              </FIRST>
              <FIRST ID="1" DESC="TEXT9">
                <END/>
              </FIRST>
              <FIRST ID="2" DESC="TEXT10">
                <END/>
              </FIRST>
            </SUBLOOP>
          </FIRSTLOOP>
          <FIRSTLOOP ID="2" DESC="TEXT11">
            <SUBLOOP>
              <FIRST ID="-1" DESC="TEXT12">
                <END>
                  <FULL IDFIRSTLOOP="0" IDFIRST="-1" />
                  <FULL IDFIRSTLOOP="1" IDFIRST="-1" />
                </END>
              </FIRST>
              <FIRST ID="0" DESC="TEXT13">
                <END>
                  <FULL IDFIRSTLOOP="0" IDFIRST="-1" />
                  <FULL IDFIRSTLOOP="1" IDFIRST="0" />
                </END>
              </FIRST>
              <FIRST ID="1" DESC="TEXT14">
                <END>
                  <FULL IDFIRSTLOOP="1" IDFIRST="1" />
                </END>
              </FIRST>
              <FIRST ID="2" DESC="TEXT15">
                <END>
                  <FULL IDFIRSTLOOP="1" IDFIRST="1" />
                </END>
              </FIRST>
              <FIRST ID="1" DESC="TEXT16">
                <END>
                  <FULL IDFIRSTLOOP="1" IDFIRST="2" />
                </END>
              </FIRST>
              <FIRST ID="2" DESC="TEXT17">
                <END>
                  <FULL IDFIRSTLOOP="1" IDFIRST="2" />
                </END>
              </FIRST>
            </SUBLOOP>
          </FIRSTLOOP>
       </SECONDLEVEL>
    </FIRSTLEVEL>
```

The XML represented indicates in the FIRSTLOOP which outermost level I have to take into account. The FIRST indicates the position (ID) and the description (DESC) of what I have to insert. If a FULL field is present it means that that object must also be inserted in other cycles. For example, if IDFIRSTLOOP is 0 it means that I have to insert that item in the outermost loop called 0. IDFIRST indicates the index of the sub-cycle in which I have to insert that item. If these two indices are already present, fill in the N field, otherwise a new object is created with L and N in the position indicated by FIRST and FIRSTLOOP with the FIRST label in DESC.
I proceeded to create a code that tries with a for loop to iterate through all the XML and create a resulting JSON like this:

```
{
  "0": {
    "-1": {
      "L": "TEXT2",
      "N": {
        "-1": {
            "L": "TEXT7",
            "N": {
                "-1": {
                    "L": "TEXT12",
                    "N": {}
                }
            }
        }
        "0": {
            "L": "TEXT8",
            "N": {
                "0": {
                    "L": "TEXT13",
                    "N": {}
                }
            }
        }
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "L": "TEXT3",
      "N": {}
    },
    "2": {
      "L": "TEXT4",
      "N": {}
    },
    "3": {
      "L": "TEXT5",
      "N": {}
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "-1": {
      "L": "TEXT12",
      "N": {}
    },
    "0": {
      "L": "TEXT13",
      "N": {}
    },
    "1": {
      "L": "TEXT9",
      "N": {
        "1": {
          "L": "TEXT14",
          "N": {}
        },
        "2": {
          "L": "TEXT15",
          "N": {}
        }
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "L": "TEXT10",
      "N": {
        "1": {
          "L": "TEXT16",
          "N": {}
        },
        "2": {
          "L": "TEXT17",
          "N": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the code made by me doesn't work because the dictionary says that the IDs are duplicated and it doesn't work. How can I do? What am I doing wrong in making the code? How should I cycle all the XML to make that structure?

Here my code:

```
string json = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    JToken list = jsonParsed["FIRSTLEVEL"]["SECONDLEVEL"]["FIRSTLOOP"];
                    Dictionary<string, JObject> dict = list.ToDictionary(
                        l => (string)l["@ID"],
                        l => new JObject(
                                 new JProperty("L", l["@DESC"]),
                                 new JProperty("N", new JObject())
                             )
                    );
                    var newObj = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JObject>> {
                        {(string)jsonParsed["FIRSTLEVEL"]["SECONDLEVEL"]["FIRSTLOOP"]["@ID"], JTokentoDictionary(list)}
                    };

                    json += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
                }
```

Comment: Don’t use values for names in JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately I am obliged, I cannot change the hardware side how things are done or accepted. I just have to convert the two :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following for xml serialization :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FIRSTLEVEL));
            FIRSTLEVEL firstLevel = (FIRSTLEVEL)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    public class FIRSTLEVEL
    {
        [XmlArray("SECONDLEVEL")]
        [XmlArrayItem("FIRSTLOOP")]
        public List<FIRSTLOOP> firstLoop { get; set; }

    }
    public class FIRSTLOOP
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int ID { get; set; }


        [XmlArray("SUBLOOP")]
        [XmlArrayItem("FIRST")]
        public List<FIRST> first { get; set; }
    }
    public class FIRST
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string DESC { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, how could this solution help me? I have tried it and it gives me error because it does not recognize tags in XML. Also as output I would need a JSON and your code returns an element of type FIRSTLEVEL :(

Comment: In addition i want to serialized, not deserialized file :(

Comment: Fill the classes with data then use XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename).  The serialize is the same constructor as reading.  The use serializer.Serialize(writer, instance of FIRSTLEVEL).  The instance should be the class with the data.

Comment: The code is to take the XML posted above and read from file into classes.  You need to write separate code to convert classes to/from json.

Comment: could you please help me by posting a code example? Thank you

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?force_isolation=true&pivots=dotnet-6-0